# Can "Page Sizer" Google Docs add-on read my Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-addon

https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/page_sizer/595382898724

The "Page Sizer" add-on to Google Docs would be wonderful!

But even though I read through their:

https://apps.burnskids.com/terms.html
and:
https://apps.burnskids.com/privacy.html

I still don't have information about that that after adding this addon to my Google Docs, will they be able to read all my Google Docs as a third party?

Or they just add some CSS to Google Docs and they cannot see what am I writing in my "private" Google Docs files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tl;Dr: Yes, Page Sizer can read your Google documents.

---

To review the permissions that the app requires to be installed, click on the Install button, then dialog asking for the Google account to be used will be shown, then the OAuth consent screen will be shown. This dialog list the permissions required and next to each of them there is a button for each of them that show a description of what that permission allows to the app to do.

Below is a screen shot of the OAuth consent screen shown to me few moments ago:

[image]

Comment: I didn't went so far pressing the install button, Many thanks!